# Combine sink only receives outputs after they have all been published

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to perform some iterative work, and use Combine to publish the progress (0.0 - 100.0) using a `CurrentValueSubject`, which my ViewModel will then subscribe to

*(Edit: the ViewModel controls a SwiftUI `ProgressView`, which is why `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` is used)*

What I'm seeing is that the outputs are being published, but `sink` doesn't receive any of them until the publisher has completed.

Here's a simplified example:

```swift
// Class that performs iterative calculations and publish its progress

class JobWorker {
  private var subject: CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>

  private var progress = 0.0

  init() {
    self.subject = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(progress)
  }

  func getPublisher() {
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func doWork() {
    let tasks = [1,2,3,4,5]
    tasks.forEach { num in

      // ... perform some calculations ...

      self.incrementProgress(20.0)
    }
  }

  func incrementProgress(_ by: Double) {
    progress += by
    if progress >= 100.0 {
      print("PUBLISH completion")
      subject.send(completion: .finished)
    } else {
      print("PUBLISH value \(progress)")
      subject.send(progress)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
// ViewModel that subscribes to JobWorker's publisher and updates the progress in the view

final class JobViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var progress: Double = 0.0

  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  private var jobWorker: JobWorker

  init() {
    self.jobWorker = JobWorker()
  }

  func runJob() {
    self.jobWorker
      .getPublisher()
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .handleEvents(
          receiveSubscription: { _ in
              print("RECEIVE subscription")
          },
          receiveOutput: { value in
              print("RECEIVE output \(value)")
          },
          receiveCompletion: { _ in
              print("RECEIVE completion")
          },
          receiveCancel: {
              print("RECEIVE cancel")
          },
          receiveRequest: { _ in
              print("RECEIVE demand")
          }
      )
      .sink { [weak self] (completion) in
          guard let self = self else { return }
          print("SINK completion")
      } receiveValue: { [weak self] (value) in
          guard let self = self else { return }
          print("SINK output \(value)")
          self.progress = value
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    print("*** DO WORK ***")
    self.jobWorker.doWork()
  }
}
```

Calling `JobViewModel.runJob` results in the following output:

```
RECEIVE subscription
RECEIVE demand
RECEIVE output 0.0
SINK output 0.0
*** DO WORK ***
PUBLISH value 20.0
PUBLISH value 40.0
PUBLISH value 60.0
PUBLISH value 80.0
PUBLISH value 100.0
PUBLISH completion
RECEIVE output 20.0
SINK output 20.0
RECEIVE output 40.0
SINK output 40.0
RECEIVE output 60.0
SINK output 60.0
RECEIVE output 80.0
SINK output 80.0
RECEIVE output 100.0
SINK output 100.0
RECEIVE completion
SINK completion
```

After the `CurrentValueSubject` is first initialized, all of the outputs are published before `handleEvents` or `sink` receives anything.

Instead, I would have expected the output to show `PUBLISH output x`, `RECEIVE output x`, `SINK output x` for each of the outputs, followed by the completion.

Comment: What if you delete `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`?

Comment: @matt the messages arrive in the correct order! But I'm trying to update the UI from the `sink` method, and it doesn't seem to do anything. The progress bar just jumps from 0 to 100. (edit: posted before finished typing)

Comment: @matt I'd also love to know why `receive(on:)` changes the behaviour, if you have any idea?

Comment: I believe that the question you actually asked has been answered. Your question says nothing about a progress bar. The reason why the `receive(on:)` causes the issue you asked about is pretty obvious. I suggest you delete the question and start over. This time ask the question you actually want to know the answer to! You'll get better help.

Comment: @matt my original question mentions a **View Model** that publishes a `progress` variable. I can edit it to mention there's a `Progress` component observing that value. It's not obvious to me why `receive(on:)` would change the behaviour or else I wouldn't have posted this question on StackOverflow. I'd agree you've mostly answered the question, and I don't really understand the hostility.

Comment: I'm unclear what you want at this point, sorry. I'm not being hostile, I'm trying to guide you to improve the question so that you get the help you actually need.

Comment: It seems to me that the real issue lies in a completely different place. As long as you are running `doWork` on the main thread, naturally you are blocking the interface from changing (e.g. your Progress). That's got nothing to do with Combine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your worker on the same thread where you are collecting the results.

Because you are doing a `receive(on:)` on the main DispatchQueue each value that passes through `receive(on:)` is roughly equivalent to putting a new block on the main queue to be executed when the queue is free.

Your worker fires up, executing synchronously on the main queue.  While it's running, the main queue is tied up and not available for other work.

As the worker does its thing, it is publishing results to the subject, and as part of the publisher pipeline `receive(on:)` queues up the delivery of each result to the main queue, waiting for that queue to be free.  The critical point, however, is that the *main queue won't be free to handle those blocks, and report results, until the worker is done because the worker itself is tying up the main queue*.

So none of your results are reported until after all the work is one.

I suspect what you want to do is run your work in a different context, off the main thread, so that it can complete asynchronously and only report the results on the main thread.

Here's a playground, based on your code, that does that:

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

class JobWorker {
    private var subject = CurrentValueSubject<Double, Never>(0)
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Double, Never> {
        get { subject.eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    }
    
    func doWork() async {
        do {
            for subtask in 1...5 {
                guard !Task.isCancelled else { break }

                print("doing task \(subtask)")
                self.incrementProgress(by: 20)

                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
            }
        } catch is CancellationError {
            print("The Tasks were cancelled")
        } catch {
            print("An unexpected error occured")
        }
    }
    
    private func incrementProgress(by: Double) {
        subject.value = subject.value + by;
        if subject.value >= 100 {
            subject.send(completion: .finished)
        }
    }
}

let worker = JobWorker()
let subscription = worker.publisher
    .print()
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { _ in
        print("done")
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("New Value Received \(value)")
    }

Task {
    await worker.doWork()
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I made your `doWork` function an `async` function so I could execute it from an independent `Task`.  I also added a delay because it makes the asynchronous nature of the code a bit easier to see.

In the "main thread, I create a `JobWorker` and subscribe to its publisher, but to do the work I create a task and run `doWork` in that separate task.  Progress is reported in the main thread, but the work is being done (and completed) in a different execution context.